# User login overwrites user fields

Tags: django, ldap, django-authentication, python-ldap

I have a Django app which uses LDAP as the authentication backend.

I'm not sure whether it's the LDAP module or just Django itself but, if a user changes their email address, first name or last name and then logs out and back in again, the values revert to their original values (ie. the ones obtained from the LDAP record).

Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour before and is there any way to prevent it?

The problem I have is that the email addresses in the LDAP records are incorrect and need updating but I have no control over them. The only thing I can control is the Django user database.

Comment: And of course, as soon as I post the question, I find the answer.

For those that are interested, there is a setting in the LDAP module called AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER which you need to set to False to make sure it doesn't update every time.

Comment: You should be able to post an answer to this question yourself and accept it (you might have to wait a day or two)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are interested, the solution was that there is a setting in the LDAP module called AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER which you need to set to False to make sure it doesn't update every time.